# Set variable width of :before and :after elements in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/fabric-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-left-bg.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 516px;
    height: 2152px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#wrapper::after {
    content: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-right-bg.png);
    display: block;
    width: 826px;
    height: 2013px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/r9Lkr0tq/)

Is there a way using CSS to reduce the size of the left and right background images using `::before` and `::after`?

At the moment they remain the same size, I want them to reduce in size depending on the browser width, is this possible with CSS without using a load of media queries? Don't mind using jQuery if I have to...

Comment: Set a width of the pseudo elements in `%`. Also note it's `:before` and `:after`, only one `:` required.

Comment: Any reason for using pseudo elements and not multiple background images on the `.wrapper`?

Comment: Nope, didn't realise you could use multiple images on one element @Aaron

Comment: @nsilva Ive provided a working example of this for you to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

> When using multiple background images the 1st layer/image is the top layer
>   in the stacking order, the next/2nd image in the stacking order will display below that and so it continues... Finally apply standard background styles (size,
>   repeat and position) add these in the same order as the images,
>   seperating each with commas.

```css
html,body {height: 100%;margin: 0;}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-left-bg.png),
url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-right-bg.png),
url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/fabric-bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat; /* 1st, 2nd, 3rd image */
  background-position: top left, top right, center center;
  background-size: 20% 100%, 20% 100%, 300px 222px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: This is great @Aaron, the only issue is that fabric-bg.png needs to be a repeated background, is this still possible when the other two backgrounds shouldn't be repeated.

Comment: thes takes care of the repeating backgrounds `background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;` @nsilva If you read my comments above, you will see that you can apply those styles in the same order as the images are applied, which will apply them to that specific background image.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case is it possible to set fabric-bg as 300x222px repeated as at the moment that element looks to be streched causing the pixelation @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9Lkr0tq/2/)

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/fabric-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-left-bg.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  top:0;
}

#wrapper:after {
  content: "";
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/trampology-right-bg.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  z-index: 10
}
```